# Need to control Maven Version Numbers for multiple projects

Tags: maven, versioning, release-management

It's a long story. My current place uses Ant for builds. They create about 20 different foundation class jars that are used in multiple projects. Originally, the projects would check in the particular versions of the various jars they needed and then never updated them. That meant that each application had incompatible jars with other projects and our servers. Hilarity ensued.

To handle this, I immediately brought in a Maven repository, and integrated Ivy into our Ant builds. No more checking in jars. Instead, you fetch the correct version from the Maven repository. Originally, I expected the developers to keep the version numbers in the `ivy.xml` up to date, but they never did. Instead, the Ivy integration and setup depends upon an external Subversion project. This allowed me to integrate Ivy with minimal changes to the old `build.xml` files. I added a `ivy.version.properties` file to that external ivy project and maintain the version numbers of various jars in there. There's a corporate wide version number.

The various projects use the `${corporate.version}` property for our foundation jars version numbers. When I update that `ivy.version.properties` file, all projects get updated with the right version number for our foundation classes. We use `<ivy:makepom>` to generate a `pom.xml` for our projects and use this to deploy our jars and wars into our Maven repository.

The result: I no longer have to worry about the developers keeping the version numbers of their projects in sync. I, as the release engineer handle that by updating that one `ivy.version.properties` file. All projects are in sync.

---

Now, we're moving to Maven, and I want to be able to do the same thing. I doubt developers will remember to update their `pom.xml` with the correct version numbers, so I want to read that in from another file, and use that.

There are two issues: One is that Maven first reads in the version number of a project before it executes any goal. No version number in the `pom.xml`, no version number for the generated jar.

Even if I manage to get by that first step, we have the fact that the pom.xml has no version number in it for foundation classes. When Maven pulls down the `pom.xml` to get the dependencies, it can't figure out which revision.

Yes, I could put that into a corporate `pom.xml` and have that as a parent project for all of the other projects. We already have a parent project to help set up various aspect of all projects. I could put a foundation class version number in there. However, that means that the developers now have to update the parent project's version number with each release. If developers can't be trusted to update the version number of their project with each release, what makes you think they'll do that with the parent's version for each release?

I know other people must have run into a similar issue. How do you handle this?

I could have an Ant script that generates the `pom.xml` from a template `pom.xml`, but that seems a bit silly.

I was wondering if is it possible for Maven to generate a `pom.xml` on the fly and then to use that to continue the executing the right goal. For example, I type in `mvn package`, and Maven will take a `template.pom.xml` file, fill in the missing version numbers to generate a `generated.pom.xml` file, then execute `mvn package` on that generated pom.

Or, is there a better way to solve this issue? Basically, I need to control the version number of our releases across all projects. This way, all projects are using the same version of our foundation classes. Also, I control some other versions of other jars (like log4j) this way. I've done this with Ant and Ivy, and now I want to move to Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to create a pom.xml with all the dependencies to your packages in its  and then import it in your developer project paren pom.xml using import

So, in the project parent POM:

```
<properties>
  <corporate.version>...</corporate.version>
<properties>
...
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.libs</groupId>
      <artifactId>foundation<artifactId>
      <version>${corporate.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

So for new set of foundation libraries, you deploy a new pom.xml with all the versions in it and update the `${corporate.version}` in the relevant parent pom.xml file. You can even have when the versions are not yet fixed define a -SNAPSHOT artifact with these version numbers.

for more information, see: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies

Comment: I was going to do it this way. However, in order to change my _corporate version_, I have to update my master `pom.xml`. That means the developer still has to update the project's `pom.xml`. Instead of updating their project's `<version>`, they have to update the _parent's_ `<version>` number.

Comment: The simple solution would be for you to update directly the pom.xml file. Is there a reason you cannot touch the file in source control? Else, even using a template to generate the pom.xml before the actual maven build is dangerous: developers will modify the pom.xml file directly, forgetting that it is not source controlled and that the template file is to be modified instead

Comment: There are 100+ projects with 40+ foundation jars that all must be in sync with the version numbering. I can't depend upon the developers, and maintaining 100+ pom.xml to make sure everything is in sync is a bit much. The Ivy solution I have allows me to update one file, and all projects are updated. I could use a template for the pom.xml and use a svn hook to prevent developers from adding a file called `pom.xml` to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

We actually have the same kind of problem and I know that there is trade-off between "lazy programmers" who never update their poms and the stability aspect: Changing the versions of the foundation jars "suddenly" which may cause unexpected build fails.

If you really want the behaviour you describe, I would put the desired dependencies into a SNAPSHOT pom and use it either as a parent pom or import it as a BOM. In this way, you can change the content and everybody pulls in the new content with the next update.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided that this a stupid idea and should never have been done. It's the developers' responsibility to update their own damn POM and make sure they're pulling the correct version. This is the way it really should be and developers should simply learn to do it (what's the technical term? ...oh yeah) the ***Correct Way***.

I originally implemented this because the company had something like this (which wasn't working) and I had problems getting the developers to do what should be their job. And, the developers liked it because I was now officially responsible when something goes wrong rather than them. It's what you get when you do someone else's job.

I've convinced the company to stop trying to keep all our core jars (the jars used in our other projects) and our releases at the same version number. Instead, every project will have its own versioning. Jars will version only when there's an actual change and not when we force an upgrade to the version. And, the developers must know what versions of the various jars they depend upon.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [maven-release-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/).  This plugin can stamp a version number on all pom.xml files.  The plugin also understands version control and knows how to tag a maven project for release (or branching).